# Do I need 3 divs to achieve that?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to achieve something like this in CSS (see picture below).

The way I'm planning to do it is to create 3 DIVs: red one and blue one (with one pixel space btw both) and wrap them in a 3rd container (to ease the placement).

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: What’s that supposed to be in the end, some kind of button/navigation item? Then there’s surely gonna be better suited elements than DIVs …

Comment: Will be a banner to advertise a new service

Comment: You might be able to do it with two div's, the parent and one child, but three div's gives you a lot more design flexibility.

Comment: _“Will be a banner to advertise a new service”_ – one `a` and one `span` (or `strong`, `em`, `b`, `i` … depending on whether or not you want to place any kind of emphasis on one of the text parts or not) inside it should do then. A third, outer container element seems completely superfluous, positioning/aligning the `a` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your main question is - No.

You can achieve this result in almost hundred ways. Best practice depends on the flexibility you need with these elements to reduce redundancy.

### I would do something like this:

- Build one parent-wrapper
- float the left-item (Nouveau)
- Text Cats & Dogs inside the parent-wrapper

### HTML

```
<section class='advertising'>
  <span class='new'>> Nouveau</span>
  Cats &amp; Dogs
</section>
```

### CSS

```
.advertising {
  width: 400px;
  line-height: 45px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #4DA6FF;
}

.advertising .new {
  background-color: #FF4000;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 7px;
  margin-right: 7px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ffffff; /* 1px border to the right */
}
```

### Live-Example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aoDKH

Comment: Great, thanks for your help. How could I leave a 1 pixel empty space between the blue and the red DIV in your example, Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. You can achieve this effect by adding a 1px-white-border to the right of the ".new"-span

Comment: One simple text banner hardly constitutes its own `section` IMHO …

Comment: @CBroe you're absolutely right. I'm definitively not sure, in which context he wants to use them, it should just give him an idea how to achieve the result. A `span` should probably not be used as `inline-block` as well. He can rename the `section` as well as the `span` with `div` if it suites better to him.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a better way, but the first thing that comes to my mind is just create 3 divs, use margin properties and you'll have the same result. No reason to make anything difficult with task this easy.

Answer (score 0):

Container is in your hand to use or not. But you need at least 2 DIVs to make your own plan.

You can use a DIV with background blue and width of 300px (for example) and a DIV on the blue DIV with background red and width of 160px (for example)